# Авторизация vk на Java

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, http

Мне нужно получить token пользователя VK, зная его логин и пароль. Но у меня это никаким образом не получается сделать!
А именно у меня не выходит сделать POST запрос с логином и паролем.
Скиньте пример, пожалуйста.

Мне нужно такого рода: 
String getToken(String email, String pass, String score)

Мой код не просите, я часов 5 уже сижу, я что только не делал. У меня просто нету конечного кода.

Я смог только получить html страницу авторизации вк и все. дальше ничего не выходит.

Отталкивался от этого:

```
"https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?" +
                "client_id=5416440&" +
                "scope=messages&" +
                "redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&" +
                "display=mobile&" +
                "v=5.50&" +
                "response_type=token"
```

Comment: Подробнее пожалуйста, вход будет отличаться в зависимости от того, что это. Android, JavaFX какой нибудь или клиент + сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites
тебе вот сюда... там всё русским языком написано.

> ### Авторизация сайтов
>
> Для доступа к API ВКонтакте с Вашего сайта предусмотрен механизм серверной авторизации на базе протокола OAuth 2.0. Этот метод позволяет реализовать безопасную аутентификацию пользователей на Вашем сайте через ВКонтакте и получить доступ к API с сервера Вашего приложения.
>
> Процесс авторизации сайта состоит из 4-х шагов:
>
> 1. Открытие окна браузера для аутентификации пользователя на сайте ВКонтакте.
> 2. Разрешение пользователем доступа к своим данным.
> 3. Передача сайту значения **code** для получения ключа доступа.
> 4. Получение сервером приложения ключа доступа **access_token** для доступа к API ВКонтакте.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/145548)

Comment: @tCode вот так исправил